# Density of transformation of a random vector with dependent values. Density of random variables function. Distribution of random variables function

Tags: statistics

Given set of dependent variables

$$X_1,X_2,X_3$$

With density function

$$
(X_1,X_2,X_3) \sim f_{X}(X_1,X_2,X_3)
$$

We need to get density distribution of some transformation:

$$z=h(X_1, X_2, X_3)$$
$$f_{z}(z) - ?$$

It can be for example something like

$h(X_1,X_2)=\cos{(X_1)}X_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything below also works of independent random variables, because if $X_1, X_2, X_3$ is independent, then vector distribution out of them is just
$f_{X}(X_1,X_2,X_3)=f_{1}(X_1)f_{2}(X_2)f_{3}(X_3)$

Random vector is:
$X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$

So:

## 2 variables case:

Random vector:
$X=(X_1,X_2)$

With distribution:

$(X_1,X_2) \sim f_{X}(x_1,x_2)$

And transform function

$z=h(X)=h(X_1,X_2)$

$H=(h(X),X_{2})=(H_{1},H_{2})$

$H_{1}=h(X)$, $h^{-1}(H)=X_{1}$

$$f_{z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(h^{-1}(z,h_{ 2}),h_{2})\left|{\frac{dh^{-1}(z,h_2)}{dz}}\right| dh_{2}dh_{3}$$

## 3 variables case

$H=(h(X),X_{2},X_{3})=(H_{1},H_{2},H_{3})$ - some vector transformation

$H_{1}=h(X)$, $h^{-1}(H)=X_{1}$

inverse function of $h$ relative to $X_{1}$ - instead of $X_{1}$ you can take any $X_{i}$

$H_{2}=X_{2}$

$H_{3}=X_{3}$

Find jacobian determinant of space transformation.

$$J=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{dh^{-1}}{dH_{1}} & \frac{dh^{-1}}{dH_{2}} & \frac{dh^{-1}}{dH_{3}} \newline
0 & 1 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

$\det{J}=\frac{dh^{-1}}{dH_{1}}$

So now if we plug in $h^{-1}$ into original distribution rule
we will preserve area under transformations.

$f_{H}(H)=f_{X}(h^{-1}(H),H_{2},H_{3})\left|{\frac{dh^{-1}}{dH_ {1}}}\right|$

Now we can take integral of it. to get rid of $H_2$ and $H_3$ and will be left with $H_1$ variable distribution - exactly what we need.

$$f_{H_1}(h_{1})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{H}(h_{1},h_{2 },h_{3})dh_{2}dh_{3}$$

$$f_{z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(h^{-1}(z,h_{ 2},h_{3}),h_{2},h_{3})\left|{\frac{dh^{-1}(z,h_2,h_{3})}{dz}}\right| dh_{2}dh_{3}$$

And it holds true for any amount of random variables.
You just plug more integrals over all remaining variables.

Or you can have transformation from like 10 random variables to just 3, and you will need to compute distribution of resulting random vector of size 3.
It can be done in similar way, all that will change is variables that you integrate out of distribution and jacobian matrix determinant **will** become messy.

Jacobian elements under index $ij$ can be found like this

$$J_{ij}=\frac{dx_{i}}{dH_{j}}$$

Some of explanations can be found here. I am just posting formula.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Random_Variables